# Хочу скомпилить с помошю maven итог Error: Could not find or load main class Main.class

Tags: maven

Main калсс в D:\java\mvnTst5\src\main\java\lol\Main.class

```
package lol;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

prom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                lol.Main
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Лезу в D:\java\mvnTst5> пишу mvn compile

Потом D:\java\mvnTst5\target\classes\lol> и пишу java Main.class

Error: Could not find or load main class Main.class

Второй день сижу не могу понят почему та а?

Comment: Потом лезть надо в `D:\java\mvnTst5\target\classes` и выполнять оттуда `java lol.Main`

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev делал

D:\java\mvnTst5\target\classes\lol>java lol.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class lol.Main

D:\java\mvnTst5\target\classes\lol>java lol.Main.class
Error: Could not find or load main class lol.Main.class

Comment: Внимательнее смотрим на мой комментарий.